# Three Google Maps on two pages (Google Maps V3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Hello I am working on this example (example above)

and if I add a new map to this code, it will work, but only on this same page, if I add a map to the new page, then it crashes (map doesn't appear on the new page, it only works on the first page.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Shreerang/Pp8gT/light/ sorry but I coulnd't add jsfidle link to the post.

Comment: when you say on two pages, can you expand what you mean?

Comment: There can be many reasons for this. Either you aren't including google map script in second page or you don't have the element with the Id mentioned in code. Share the relevant code as well as your issues.

Comment: @CharlesA I mean, that I have firstpage.html and secondpage.html just two normal pages.

Comment: You shouldn't have a problem with multiple google maps on the same page. Can you post a fiddle link like above?

Comment: Did my answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

To edit your jsfiddle, do the following:

Add to the html:

```
<div id="map_canvas_3" style="top: 10px; left: 125px; width:210px; height:220px"></div>
```

Add to the javascript:

```
var latlng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(29.579943,78.330006);

 var myOptions3 =
 {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latlng3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
 };

var map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_3"), myOptions3);

var myMarker3 = new google.maps.Marker(
{
    position: latlng3,
    map: map3,
    title:"TEST"
});
```

Should work fine.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/56HMR/2/